# How to verify, that no method of a class has been called?

Tags: java, jmockit

I want to check, that no method of a given class was called. Right now I am doing this by putting into the verification-block a single line for every method like shown in this listing:

```
new Verifications() {
    {
        myClass.method1();
        times = 0;

        myClass.method2();
        times = 0;
    }
};
```

The problem is, that if someone adds method3 to MyClass and calls it, my test won't notice that. Is there a more generic way to do this? Something like `myClass.*; times = 0;`?

Comment: is this an mocked instance of the class on which you want to monitor ?

Comment: Yes. myClass is a mocked instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the answer of YoungHobbit in mind I found the answer myself:

```
new FullVerifications(myClass) {};
```

does the trick.

Comment: As my answer is not required and not relevant to the problem. I will remove it.